# How are they calculating the Time Complexity for this Problem

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Problem 6: Find the complexity of the below program:

```
void function(int n) 
{ 
    int i = 1, s =1; 
    while (s <= n) 
    { 
        i++; 
        s += i; 
        printf("*"); 
    } 
}
```

Solution: We can define the terms ‘s’ according to relation si = si-1 + i. The value of ‘i’ increases by one for each iteration. The value contained in ‘s’ at the ith iteration is the sum of the first ‘i’ positive integers. If k is total number of iterations taken by the program, then while loop terminates if: 1 + 2 + 3 ….+ k = [k(k+1)/2] > n So k = O(√n).

Time Complexity of the above function O(√n).

FROM: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-set-5-practice-problems/

Looking it over and over.

Apparently they are saying the Time Complexity is O(√n).  I don't understand how they are getting to this result, and i've tried looking at this problem over and over.  Can anyone break it down into detail?

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the `while`-loop, we have `s = 1; i = 1`, and `n` is some (big) number. In each step of the loop, the following is done,

1. Take the current `i`, and increment it by one;
2. Add this new value for `i` to the sum `s`.

It is not difficult to see that successive updates of `i` forms the sequence `1, 2, 3, ...`, and `s` the sequence `1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3, ...`. By [a result attributed to the young Gauss](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html), the sum of the first `k` natural numbers `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k` is `k(k + 1) / 2`. You should recognise that the sequence `s` fits this description, where `k` indicates the number of iterations!

The `while`-loop terminates when `s > n`, which is now equivalent to finding the lowest iteration number `k` such that `(k(k + 1) / 2) > n`. Simplifying for the asymptotic case, this gives a result such that `k^2 > n`, which we can simplify for `k` as `k > sqrt(n)`. It follows that this algorithm runs in a time proportional to `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I get it now.  Looks like I need to brush up on some stuff, and forgot about the Formula by Gauss.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that `k` is the first integer such that `k(k+1)/2 > n` (otherwise the loop would have stopped earlier).

Then `k-1` cannot have this same property, which means that `(k-1)((k-1)+1)/2 <= n` or `(k-1)k/2 <= n`. And we have the following sequence of implications:

```
(k-1)k/2 <= n  →  (k-1)k  <= 2n
               →  (k-1)^2 < 2n                    ; k-1 < k
               →   k <= sqrt(2n) + 1              ; solve for k
                     <= sqrt(2n) + sqrt(2n)       ; 1 < sqrt(2n)
                      = 2sqrt(2)sqrt(n)
                      = O(sqrt(n))
```